# Problem with merging user properties in Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

1. Suppose I have a file on trunk called file.txt. I put a property on it, say `color` with the value `red`.
2. Now I copy trunk to a branch B.
3. On branch B I change file.txt's `color` property to `green`.
4. Now independently on trunk, I also change file.txt's `color` property to `green`.
5. When I merge the branch B back to trunk, I get a merge conflict, even though both the branch and the trunk are trying to change the property to the same value. If I bring up KDiff3 to edit the conflict, even it shows the base is `red`, mine as `green` and theirs as `green`. In the bottom window KDiff3 shows no conflict, it picks `green`.

It appears SVN isn't paying attention to the property value at all. It just notices both the branch and the trunk have made a change and calls it a conflict. Why? Is this a bug or intentional behavior? Is their a work around?

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.6.15 which I think is using Subversion 1.6.16.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked about this on the SVN user's mailing list and a SVN developer submitted it as a bug to the SVN bug tracker:

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3919

Edit: I submitted a patch and now it is fixed! Thanks to the Subversion crew, especially Stefan Sperling.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a `*.prej` with content like:

> Trying to change property 'color' from
>   'red' to 'green', but property already
>   exists with value 'green'.

You have to read such `.prej` files and resolve the conflict manually, despite the values being the same.

You may also want to look here for some relevant decision made by the TortoiseSVN team: http://svn.haxx.se/tsvn/archive-2008-09/0212.shtml

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate that post is now. I can edit the conflict using TortoiseSVN and it brings up KDiff3, for example. I did not see a .prej file either, but I'll look again.

Comment: @Brian Neal Just mark it as resolve later and see. I was able to replicate this on 1.6.15

Comment: Yeah but we have hundreds of files like this and it is blocking a merge. Bummer.